# Is it possible to use form and div tag inside p tag in html?

Tags: html, css

I have been created simple web page using html, css and some scripts.

Here is my jsfiddle i tried: http://jsfiddle.net/67x8cyp9/

```
<p>
 <img class="text-wrap" align="right" src="img/9780143332497.jpg">
 <div class="caption">
    <form method="get" action="9780143332497.png">
       <button type="submit">Download!</button>
    </form>
 </div>
</p>
```

Is it correct to use `<form>` tag and `<div>` tag inside `<p>` tag?

And also, how to set download button under the image?

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Not it is not, `p` is a block element, but cannot contain other block elements, only inline ones. (at least in HTML4, but I don't think HTML5 changes this behaviour).

Hmm, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p), you can put a `form` in a `p`, but actually what happens is that the end of the `p` is at the beginning of the form, so not very useful.

**Update:**

To help you in your current actual problem, you can wrap the content in a `div` instead of a `p`:

```
<div class="right-figure">
    <img class="text-wrap" src="img/9780143332497.jpg">
    <div class="caption">
        <form method="get" action="9780143332497.png">
             <button type="submit">Download!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the CSS file:

```
.right-figure {
     float: right;
}
```

This will do, what you need.

**Another approach**:

By the way, you could also just use a link instead of a form:

```
<a href="9780143332497.png" target="_blank">Download!</a>
```

and format the anchor with CSS to look like a button, just like e.g. Twitter Bootstrap does.

Comment: if not, may i know  how can i fix this? @meskobalazs

Comment: Well, use a `div` for example (or the HTML5 alternatives: `nav`, `header`, `section` etc.)

Comment: Can you help me to provide jsfiddle?

Comment: in my jsfiddle, download button top of my image, i need to display under the image, here is the modified code: <p><img class="text-wrap" align="right" src="img/9780143332497.jpg"></p>
<div class="caption"><form method="get" action="file.png">
<button type="submit">Download!</button></form></div>

Comment: this is different from my jsfiddle right @meskobalazs?

Comment: You should wrap the whole thing in a `div` and using the `float` css property to place as you want it. Quick and a bit dirty solution: http://jsfiddle.net/67x8cyp9/11/

Answer (score 2):

Its NOT recommended.

According to W3 specifications, `<p>` is only allowed to contain text or 'inline' (not 'block') tags. However a `<form>` counts as 'block' content not as 'inline' content(see [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xhtml-modularization-20010410/abstract_modules.html#s%5Ftextmodule) for *Minimal Content Model* in `<p>` tag). Alternately, you may use a `<div>` to enclose your `<form>`

You may validate your html code on [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) for better clarity.

Cheers!

Comment: Is it possible to get around this by adding `display:inline` to the form's CSS?